# Storing lucene index in db (no JDBCDirectory, no file system)

Tags: database, hibernate, indexing, lucene, ramdirectory

Is there any good way to storing lucene index in db without any external library, that touches connection layer (like JDBCDirectory) and also without using file system (even temporary). RAMDirectory would be fine for me if I could get from it specific parts of the index - .cfs "file" and segment. Don't know if it's doable. Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: using Hibernate Search ?